# Can't delete entity with inheritance on doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

With this two entities

```
Entity\AbstractSurveyAnswer:
    type: entity
    table: survey_answers
    inheritanceType: JOINED
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: type_class
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        database: SurveyDatabaseAnswer
        client_text: SurveyClientTextAnswer
        client_number: SurveyClientNumberAnswer
        client_date: SurveyClientDateAnswer

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    manyToOne:
        client:
            targetEntity: Entity\Client
            joinColumn:
                name: id_client
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id

        survey:
            targetEntity: Entity\AbstractSurvey
            joinColumn:
                name: id_survey
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id
```

and

```
Entity\AbstractSurveyAnswer:
    type: entity
    table: survey_answers
    inheritanceType: JOINED
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: type_class
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        database: SurveyDatabaseAnswer
        client_text: SurveyClientTextAnswer
        client_number: SurveyClientNumberAnswer
        client_date: SurveyClientDateAnswer

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    manyToOne:
        client:
            targetEntity: Entity\Client
            joinColumn:
                name: id_client
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id

        survey:
            targetEntity: Entity\AbstractSurvey
            joinColumn:
                name: id_survey
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id
```

and I try to remove an entity with this code

```
$to_delete_answer = new SurveyDatabaseAnswer();
$to_delete_answer->setId($answer);
$storage->remove($to_delete_answer);//calls EntityManagger::remove
$storage->flush();
```

But I get the followint error message

```
Detached entity \Entity\\SurveyDatabaseAnswer@00000000204763e700007fdd1d66d304 cannot be removed
```

I don't know what is wrong with delete this entities,not tryng trying to remove ant table referenced on another table.It's someething due the inheritance type?I'm noob on doctrine  and I can't see the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your entity $to_delete_answer is not "merged", so your EntityManager cannot handle it.
Try to add `$storage->merge($to_delete_answer);` before removing your entity:

```
$to_delete_answer = new SurveyDatabaseAnswer();
$to_delete_answer->setId($answer);
$storage->merge($to_delete_answer);
$storage->remove($to_delete_answer);//calls EntityManagger::remove
$storage->flush();
```

See : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

Comment: `merge` is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine 3: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#bc-break-removed-entitymanagermerge-and-entitymanagerdetach-methods